# Maximal solution differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

Consider equations defined in $D_x = (0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$

1) Find the maximal solution to 
$$ \dot y = \frac{3t^2}{5y^4} $$
satisfying the initial value problem $y(1) = 2^{\frac{1}{5}}$

I have found the maximum solution to be $((0,\infty), (t^3+1)^\frac{1}{5})$

2) Find the maximal solution to

$$ \dot y = -\frac{2y}{5t}+\frac{3}{5y^4}$$

satisfying the IVP $y(1) = 2^{\frac{1}{5}}$. 
(HINT: Use a transformation of the form $t^{\alpha}y(t)$.

I hope someone can explain how to use the transformation to find the maximal solution.

Comment: Keyword to the answer below: This is a **Bernoulli equation** $$\dot y(t)=P(t)y(t)+Q(t)y(t)^n,$$ using the substitution $u=y^{1-n}$ it transforms into a linear DE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply both sides of $$\dot y = -\frac{2y}{5t}+\frac{3}{5y^4}$$ by $5y^4$ to get $$ 5y^4\dot y = -\frac {2}{t} y^5 +3$$

Now let $$u=y^5$$ and your equation transforms to $$ \dot u = -\frac {2}{t} u +3 $$

which is a linear equation.

Solve for $u$ and back substitute to find $y$